# How to remove the empty space around the image when displaying it in the matplotlib embedded in pyqt5 GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm working on a python based application which displays scientific single channel TIF images in a GUI using pyqt5, matplotlib and opencv.

When I run the code, the image is displayed with huge amount of empty space around it.

Please help me with removing the empty spaces and fitting the image perfectly inside the scroll area.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1138, 702)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1077, 747))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

   
    def openImage(self):
        self.img = cv2.imread("Delta1.tif",-1)
        self.height, self.width, self.channels = self.img.shape
        print("width: ",self.width)
        print("height: ",self.height)
        self.dpiw = 100
        self.dpih = 100
        self.figsize = self.width/float(self.dpiw), self.height/float(self.dpih)
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=self.figsize)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.ax = self.fig.subplots()
        self.ax.set_axis_off()
        temp_img = self.img
        self.ax.imshow(self.img, cmap="gray", vmin = 0, vmax=65535)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.canvas)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.openImage()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if QtCore.QT_VERSION >= 0x50501:
    def excepthook(type_, value, traceback_):
        traceback.print_exception(type, value, traceback)
        QtCore.qFatal('')
sys.excepthook = excepthook
```

[image]

Comment: You could try adding something like `self.fig.tight_layout(pad=0.0)` after the line `self.ax.imshow(self.img, cmap="gray", vmin = 0, vmax=65535)`

Comment: @eyllanesc  Yes, it worked perfectly well. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @eyllanesc Actually I'm quiet new to matplotlib and pyqt5. Your answer just ended 2 days of my struggle finding the answer.